# How can I put this information into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I safe the word "Good" and the numbers in a variable?

```
<div id="infoTable">
    <div class='info' label='Good' value='1' minvalue='2' maxvalue='3'></div>
    <div class='info' label='Bad' value='4' minvalue='5' maxvalue='6'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do u mean , u want to get the value of "label" and "value" in variables?

Comment: Odd markup. Use `data-*` attributes if you need to use custom attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you find the `div` they're in:

```
var theDiv = $("#infoTable div").first();
```

That uses [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to find the divs inside your `infoTable` div, then uses [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first) to get just the first one. (You can also do `var theDiv = $("#infoTable div:first");` but it's probably no more efficient.)

Then you read its attributes:

```
var theLabel = theDiv.attr("label");
var theValue = theDiv.attr("value");
// ...and so on
```

If you want the numbers as numbers rather than strings:

```
var theValue = parseInt(theDiv.attr("value"), 10);
```

Comment: @user1803348: No worries, glad that helped! BTW, I'd recommend using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) for putting non-standard attributes on elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
var objects = [];

jQuery('.info').each(function()}{
    var j = jQuery(this);
    objects.push({
        label: j.attr('label'),
        minValue: parseInt(j.attr('minvalue'), 10),
        maxValue: parseInt(j.attr('maxvalue'), 10)
    });
});
```

now you have all data in your `objects` array

Answer (score 0):

If your markup is exactly something you wrote, use this jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    var $elem = $('#infoTable .info:eq(0)');
    var label = $elem.attr('label');
    var value = $elem.attr('value');
    var minvalue = $elem.attr('minvalue');
    var maxvalue = $elem.attr('maxvalue');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript

```
document.getElementById('infoTable').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('label');//Good
document.getElementById('infoTable').getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getAttribute('label');//Bad
```